What's the simplest AWS resource I can create that responds to ICMP ping?
Long story, but we need something listening on a static IPv4 in a VPC subnet that will respond to ICMP Ping. Ideally this won’t be an EC2 instance. Things I’ve thought of, which don’t work:

NLBs, NAT Gateways, VPC Endpoints don’t respond to ping
ALBs do respond to ping but can’t have their IP address specified
ECS / Fargate: require more effort and coordination than just using EC2

The main reasons I’d rather not use an EC2 instance if I can help it is simply the management of it, with OS updates etc and needing downtime for these. I’d also need to put it in an ASG for termination protection and have it attach the ENI on boot. All perfectly doable, but it feels like there should be something out there that will just respond to ping on a specific IP.
Any creative solutions?

Is there some reason it has to be an IP address?

If you're looking for something that responds to pings from private IPv4 addresses, including across VPN and Direct Connect, a Route 53 Resolver Inbound Endpoint will do that.  They are unjustifiably expensive even when used for their intended purpose, at $0.125/hour per ENI, and you are forced to create two, so $187/month is the cost of this non-solution solution, making the EC2 option pretty attractive.
